# How do I add a bootstrap glyphicons in laravel forms

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, glyphicons

I am trying to add bootstrap glyphicons in laravel forms and buttons. How do i do that.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>

{!! Form::submit("Upload Image", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
```

I want that Glyphicon inside that button. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use a `<button>` type of submit. Which adds more flex. Smth like this:

```
{{ Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block', 'type'=>'submit')) }}
```

Comment: @Santosraj do u have bootstrap hooked up on ur project ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile down default `app.scss` to public directory through `laravel mix` if **Laravel 5.4** which generates

```
public
----|fonts
-------|glyphicon(fonts)
----css
-------|app.css
----js
-------|app.js
```

OR

You can get fonts and css copied in public directory.

OR

You can simply use CDN the easiest way.